# Como retornar el resultado de una consulta como un array asociativo en php

Tags: php, php7

Quisiera retornar el resultado "row" de una consulta sql como un array asociativo.
Puedo hacerlo de la forma mas sencilla pero esta forma crea un indice extra.
Tengo el codigo:

```
public function getAllProductsData($categoryProduct){
    $conexion = $this->conectarBD();
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM cata_productos WHERE categoria_prod = '$categoryProduct'";
    $arrayTemp= array();
    if($result = $conexion->query($sql_query)){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Salvar datos a un arreglo de todos los elementosd de consulta
            $arrayTemp[] = $row;   //corregir esta shit
        }
        return $arrayTemp;
    }

    $conexion->close();
}
```

Es la forma mas sencilla de crear una copia de cada elemento de la consulta el resultado es:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id_prod_sistema"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["clave_prod"]=>
    string(5) "lib01"
    ["nombre_prod"]=>
    string(25) "Harry Potter La orden del"
    ["categoria_prod"]=>
    string(6) "libros"
    ["stock"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["eliminado_prod"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

Y lo que quiero es un array asociativo sin el  indice externo:

```
array(3) {
  array(6) {
    ["id_prod_sistema"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["clave_prod"]=>
    string(5) "lib01"
    ["nombre_prod"]=>
    string(25) "Harry Potter La orden del"
    ["categoria_prod"]=>
    string(6) "libros"
    ["stock"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["eliminado_prod"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Debe crear el indice para poder almacenar el valor, ejemplo:

```
$resultados = [['nombre' => 'Nombre 1', 'apellido' => 'Apellido 1'], ['nombre' => 'Nombre 1', 'apellido' => 'Apellido 1']]

echo $resultados[0], $resultados[1];
```

Se debe crear una llave para el Array.

Sí no quieres usar una llave, puedes usar un objeto, ejemplo:

```
if ($result = $conexion->query($sql_query)){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            //Salvar datos a un arreglo de todos los elementosd de consulta
            $arrayTemp[] = ['clave_prod' => $obj->clave_prod];
            // Definir la array para evitar ese error
        }
        return $arrayTemp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Y lo que quiero es un array asociativo sin el indice externo:

Eso es posible, pero sólo te servirá en el caso de que estés esperando **una fila solamente** y si es así, no necesitas el `while`.

Aparte de eso, tu código tiene lagunas. Sólo tienes un caso de `return`, dentro del `if`. Eso no es correcto, debes retornar algo siempre. Además, no puedes hacer nada después del `return`, porque lo que hay después no se ejecuta, debes hacer todo lo que tengas que hacer antes de poner `return`.

Aplicando lo dicho, podrías hacer esto:

```
public function getAllProductsData($categoryProduct){
    $conexion = $this->conectarBD();
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM cata_productos WHERE categoria_prod = '$categoryProduct'";
    $arrayTemp = array();
    if($result = $conexion->query($sql_query)){
        $arrayTemp = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
    $conexion->close();
    return $arrayTemp;
}
```

Si esperas más de una fila, el índice externo **es obligatorio**, porque es lo que servirá para distinguir cada fila. En ese caso el `while` sí es obligatorio, para mover el puntero de cada fila e irla metiendo en el array.

En ese caso, y corrigiendo las lagunas del `return` antes mencionadas, el código quedaría así:

```
public function getAllProductsData($categoryProduct){
    $conexion = $this->conectarBD();
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM cata_productos WHERE categoria_prod = '$categoryProduct'";
    $arrayTemp= array();
    if($result = $conexion->query($sql_query)){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Salvar datos a un arreglo de todos los elementosd de consulta
            $arrayTemp[] = $row;   //Esto NO es una shit
        }
    }
    $conexion->close();
    return $arrayTemp;
}
```

#### Advertencia de seguridad

El código empleado aquí es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Para neutralizar ese riesgo deberías implementar **consultas preparadas**.